# How to make font-feature-settings work with Google fonts

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

My application currently uses ttf font files. To improve performance, I was looking at using Google fonts. However, the issue I noticed is that Google fonts doesn't respect the **font-feature-settings**.

Is there a way to fix this? Please find the links to the sample code using ttf and Google fonts below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-kapitsa-o2xl8l?file=/index.html

Below is the screenshot of how it renders when using ttf and Google fonts. Notice how its different especially the letters "a" and "g".

[image]

Please find the sample code below that uses Google fonts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      href="https:/fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400;600;700;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro bold";
        src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro")
            format("ttf"),
          url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro")
            format("truetype");
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
      }
      h1,
      .h1 {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro bold";
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-weight: 700;

        line-height: 1.13;
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
        font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
        -moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
        -o-font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code that uses the TTF

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro bold";
        src: url("https://o2xl8l.csb.app/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf") format("ttf"),
          url("https://o2xl8l.csb.app/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
      }
      h1,
      .h1 {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro bold";
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-weight: 700;

        line-height: 1.13;
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
        font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
        -moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
        -o-font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm a bit lost as they appear to be two completely different typefaces. What google font are you using?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks for your reply. I'm using the Source Sans Pro font.

Comment: @Rob, I've updated the post with the sample code. In this particular instance, the StackOverflow font overrides my font and it doesn't really reproduce the actual issue. You can see how it renders the sample text compared to the screenshot. This is the reason I had to use an external link.

Comment: I don't understand 'the StackOverflow font overrides my font' - isn't it just that your font is somewhere on your system and is not picked up by the SO snippet? I've looked at your sandbox and it only gives one line of text. Could you put a complete example of code into your question (starting with <!doctype onwards) so we can at least try running it on our own systems? Thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth Appreciate your help here. I've added the complete html in the post. Please note, when you run the TTF example just wait a few seconds for the actual font to get displayed as it needs to download the TTF file until then you will only see the default font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@font-face` rule has some errors:

The `url` argument expects an **actual font file URL** like
"fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v2/...fontfileName.woff2"

#### Update: Get file URLs from css URL

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro

Will return a css containing several `@font-face` rules for different styles/weights.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v21/6xK3dSBYKcSV-LCoeQqfX1RYOo3qOK7l.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

**Unfortunately**, by default google fonts will return the **most modern font format** supported by your browser – quite likely **woff2**.
Besides, **these font files won't include font-features** [(as commented here)](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/1582#issuecomment-394168818).

#### How to get the complete font (including all glyphs and features)

- Other CDNs provide the complete font [like jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/source-sans-pro?path=TTF) in all available formats
- Download the whole font family in google fonts UI via "Download family" button (e.g [Source Sans Pro](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro))

**Drawbacks**
These files will be way bigger in file size.
If your application does not necessarily need truetype, you should at least switch to the smaller woff2 format.

#### Updated example

(Compare the lowercase **g** glyphs)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "SourceSansProFeat";
  src: url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/source-sans-pro@3.6.0/TTF/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf")
    format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "SourceSansProFeat";
  src: url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/source-sans-pro@3.6.0/TTF/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf")
    format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}

body {
  font-family: "SourceSansProFeat";
}

h1,
.h1 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.13;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.feature {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
  font-feature-settings: "ss01" on, "ss02" on, "ss03" on;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="feature">Hamburglefons (alternate glyphset)</h1>
<h1>Hamburglefons (standard glyphs)</h1>
<p>Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog <span class="feature">dog</span></p>
```

#### Rename the font-family name

Many people may have Source Sans installed locally on their system.
I did too - that's why I saw that all the functions were applied correctly. But it was my local copy that was used for rendering.

Comment: Appreciate your help on this. The url suggested by Google doesn't contain the actual font file URL. So how can I get the Gstatic Url. As per docs the URL is https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2. Also, when I tried to run your code in an html file on my local, it didn't work. I'm guessing the run code snippet on SO could be overridden by SO's font and hence it's getting displayed properly.

Comment: @Frenz: Sorry I missed the point that google font's cdn will actually serve stripped down font files - omitting additional glyphs needed for features. Updated my answer. TL;DR: you might use jsDelivr to benefit from cdn hosted font files. You might also have conflicts due to locally installed Source Sans Pro versions.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll source the font files locally for now. Google fonts don't seem to be working for me in this case. Thanks for your help.